# MPI Shared Memory for Complex Object

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I have a large-scale code that runs on many CPU cores, potentially across a number of compute nodes.  The code is in C++ and is parallelized with OpenMPI.

My code has a very large object (~10GB RAM usage) that is read from by each MPI process.  This object is updated very occasionally (and can be done by a single process, just reading in a data file).

What I've been doing so far is giving each MPI process a copy of this object; but that means I'm severely RAM-limited and can't use the full CPU power of my nodes.  So, I've been reading about shared memory in the MPI 3 specification.

My question is: what is the best way to share a complex object across MPI processes?  In all the examples I find, MPI shared memory windows are created and used to exchange simple data structures (floats, arrays of ints, etc.).  My global object is a custom class type that includes a number of member variables, some of which are pointers, and many of which are other complex class types.  Hence, I feel like I won't be able to just call `MPI_Win_allocate_shared` and pass in the address of my complex object, especially since I want to share all the info about the member variables (in particular, I want to share the underlying values of the pointer type member variables - i.e. sharing a "deep copy" across MPI processes, with all virtual memory addresses correct in each process).

Is it possible to achieve this "deep sharing" with MPI shared memory, and if so, is there a "best practice" for doing so?  Or would another library (e.g. boost interprocess) make this more feasible/straightforward for me?

P.S. If I can't figure out a good solution, I will resort to a hybrid MPI+pthreads approach, where I know I can easily have this global object on each node with pthreads.  But I'm really hoping to find an elegant MPI-only solution.

Comment: Pointers to the virtual address space of one process are meaningless in other processes unless the shared memory is mapped at precisely the same base address. What you want is not impossible to achieve: it boils down to finding a big enough hole in the intersection of all memory holes in all processes and calling `mmap()` with a preferred address, but is neither portable nor guaranteed to work each an every time. The proper solution is to use relative pointers and add the base address to the value of each pointer before dereferencing it.

Comment: Note that `MPI_Win_allocate_shared` cannot be used when the process group of the underlying communicator spans more than one shared-memory node. The usual MPI RMA should be used instead in such cases.

Comment: My plan is to use RMA, like you said, to get one copy of my object per node, and then on each node use shared memory, so there is just one copy of my object per node (that's enough to keep my memory usage minimal - just need to avoid having n copies on 1 node.)  Also, I am looking for a guaranteed, portable solution (this code needs to work reliably and should also ideally run on both Linux and Windows).  When you say "The proper solution is...," can you explain more how that technique would solve my problem?  Any pseudo/example code would also help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cross machine boundary (and you use nodes on many machines) there is no any easy way to achieve your goal. 
If you use Windows or Linux machines only (not mixing them) you can try to hack it the way for instance attaching some shared resource to virtual memory (using system API to do it efficient way). Other way could be to create create custom serialization/deserialization code for your large object and than to store it in memory as binary array (to share it between processes on the same machine). The issue is big/little endian in case you try to store just "memory dump". In case you use dedicated MPI api all endian (and data presentation issues) are properly supported for sure.
I'm not sure at the moment if PVM supports such scenario better, but in case of MPI I could start with direct usage of VM on the same machine (sharing some access key between processes only) ...

Additional answer 1:

On one machine it should be simple I think (you use Windows probably so I will focus on this platform at the moment). Endian issues and data alignment doesn't matter in such case, because I assume you compile all your stuff with the same options (and use on the same hardware). The easiest way to achieve your goal is to map to virtual memory a properly named file (name doesn't matter at the moment until you create many mappings for different objects - in such case you need some naming schema for consistency). [Sample is here for instance.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx)

After the creation of virtual memory place all the object data there (using old school memcpy or just so called placement constructors). When all the data are available already in virtual memory just send file name with a few additional attributes to all of the processes/nodes on the same machine. On the beginning of virtual memory space you can place some array with pointers to objects (with allocation address deltas for instance) for easy linkage of all the related objects if you have there more than one object (in such case the first on element in vm should contain number of elems in such array - it's just a some idea only). You can map your virtual memory to the same virtual address on every process so you don't have to manage pointers if you are not interested in it at all :) In such case no any array with pointers is necessary!

Additional plus of using virtual memory is it optimizes memory pages usage, so it will not swallow 10GB of ram in case you have such big data objects.

BTW: Windows supports direct memory pages sharing with some [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf9b18xk(v=vs.140).aspx) on sections. In CPP you have [such support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s20kdbse.aspx) for it.

Comment: Let's assume for simplicity I'm working on just one machine.  (For multiple machines, I would do something like Hristo mentioned above, using RMA to get one copy of my object per node and then use shared memory to share that copy among all the procs on that node.)  If I am on just one node, can you further explain how your binary array solution would work?  How would I get a global address and store my data there?  And how would I cast it to my desired class type?

Comment: I added the answer under "Additional answer 1" section :)
Hope it's clear what my idea was ...